# Accessing instance from within prototype function other than through "this" possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, prototype

```
var dups = new Dups($("#el"))

function Dups($el) {
 this.value = 23
 $el.on("click", this.onClick)
}

Dups.prototype.onClick = function(){
// usually "this" inside here refers to the instance (Dups)
// but because jquery changes "this", inside here "this" refers to the clicked element
// how can I access the Dups instances "this.value" from here?
   alert(this.value) // does not alert 23
}
```

My Problem is in the Dups.prototype.onClick function. Any ideas how to elegantly access the Dups instances "this" other than passing "this" (the clicked element) manually, so "this" in the prototype.onClick is the desired one, like so:

```
...
$el.on("click", function(){this.onClick(this)})
....
```

It works but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: updated my question as there were some logical errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) as a portable implementation of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function Dups($el) {
    this.value = 23;
    $el.on("click", $.proxy(this.onClick, this));
}
```

`$.proxy` gives you a new function that executes with the specified `this`:

> **jQuery.proxy( function, context )**
>   Returns: Function
>
> Description: Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.

The standard `bind` method on function objects does the same thing (and more) but isn't available everywhere.

Then you could get the clicked element through the passed `event` if you needed it:

```
Dups.prototype.onClick = function(event) {
    // event.target is what was clicked
}
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/K2BuX/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.proxy` to get a function that invokes your function with `this` bound to your object...

```
$el.on("click", $.proxy(this, 'onClick')
```